# Equivalence relation with ordered pair of integers excluding zero.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $(x,y)$ be an ordered pair of integers excluding zero. Two ordered pairs $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are equivalent if $x_1y_2 = x_2y_1$. Is this an equivalence relation? Prove or disprove.

Comment: what have you tried?  Have you looked up the definition of an equivalence relation?  Where are you stuck?  Should it be $y_1$ in the first pair?

Comment: I haven't worked too much with these types of questions before so I don't know how to even start the problem. I understand that equivalence relations have to do with reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity but that's about it.

Comment: The point of a question like this is to see if you understand the definitions.  If you don't, look them up.  Reflexive says $(x,y)$ is equivalent to $(x,y)$ for all $x,y$.  Plug that into your definition and see if it is true.  Similarly for the other two.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$x_1y_2=x_2y_1$ iff $\frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{y_1}{y_2}$

HINT 2 (thanks @hardmath)

$x_1y_2=x_2y_1$ iff $\frac{x_1}{y_1} = \frac{x_2}{y_2}$

Comment: This is perhaps not such a good hint as $\frac{x_1}{y_1} = \frac{x_2}{y_2}$.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah, that one works too and probably would make it even more clear, you're right! I'll add it to the Answer, thanks!